# What I want is free video editing software , I should be able to pick or cut video parts from any timeline by typing or moving the digital timeline?

Tags: video-editor, windows

ie.,

a)If I want to keep from 10 seconds to 20 seconds of the video then I should be able type “10” , “20”;

b)I don’t want 21 to 35 seconds;

c)If I want from 36 to 43 seconds of the video then I should be able type “36” , “43”?

d) combine (a) & (b)

You might be wondering why I require to type the numbers ?
This is because , if I don't type the timeline numbers. the clipping is not very accurate. In  YouCut Android App this option is there. But not 100%. Similar thing I am looking for in Windows for free.

Answer (score 1):

the ffmpeg commands are

```
ffmpeg -y -i Sony_HDR_AX2000.mts -ss 10 -to 20 -c copy out_a.ts
```

for the case of a), and

```
ffmpeg -y -i Sony_HDR_AX2000.mts -ss 36 -to 43 -c copy out_b.ts
```

for the case of c)

Then, prepare a *list.txt* file as

```
# this is a comment
file './out_a.ts'
file './out_b.ts'
```

the ffmpeg concat files command is

```
ffmpeg -y -f concat -safe 0 -i list.txt -c copy out_d.ts
```

for case d)

References:

- https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking
- https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate